# Trouble understanding construction of quadratic variation of martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times, quadratic-variation

I am struggling to understand the construction presented in my lecture notes of the quadratic variation $A_t$ of a continuos, square integrable $(\mathcal G_t)$-martingale $M_t$. The idea of the proof is to construct $A_\cdot$ as a suitable limit of discrete quadratic variations of $M_\cdot$, along certain random grids with mesh tending to zero.

For this purpose define a sequence of stopping times $\tau_k^n$ ($n$ controls the "mesh" of the grid) as follows:

$$\tau_k^0 = k \ \ \ \text{for $k \ge 0$}$$

and for $n \ge 1$, by induction,

$$\tau_0^n = 0$$
and for $l \ge 0$, on the event $\{ \tau_k^{n-1} \le \tau_l^n < \tau_{k+1}^{n-1}\}$, $k \ge 0$, 
$$\tau_{l+1}^n = \inf \left\{ t \ge \tau_l^n: |M_t - M_{\tau_l^n}| \ge \frac 1n\right\} \wedge \left(\tau_l^n + \frac 1n\right) \wedge \tau_{k+1}^{n-1}$$

Already I have some trouble with the definition; intuitively it is the first time when your process grows more than $\frac 1n$ at most at a distance of $\frac 1n$ since the previous point on the grid. I don't know why we take the  second minimum though or what exactly means "on the event": what about all the $\omega$ not on the event $\{ \tau_k^{n-1} \le \tau_l^n < \tau_{k+1}^{n-1}\}$? how do you define $\tau_{l+1}^n$ for those? Also, who is $k$ exactly in the previous definition?

As a result of this confusion, I am not able to understand why the following properties are true. Lecture notes simply state that it's easy to see using continuity of $M_\cdot$ that for every $\omega \in \Omega$ we have

> $$ \tau_k^n(\omega) \le \tau^n_{k+1}(\omega), \ \ \  \text{for $n,k
>  \ge 0$}$$

This makes sense for $\omega$ in that event, but what about other $\omega$?

> $$\{\tau_0^n(\omega), \tau_1^n(\omega), \dots \} \subseteq
>  \{\tau_0^{n+1}(\omega), \tau_1^{n+1}(\omega) \dots \}$$

No idea why this would be the case.

> $$\tau_k^n(\omega) \to \infty \ \ \text{as $k \to \infty$}$$

Not sure about this either.

The problem is that I cannot "visualize" the grid, I have no clue about the "spirit" of the proof. It seems to me a huge mess of symbols put there for no particularly good reason! Any help is much appreciated, even just a comment or something to make me gain intuition about this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: e.g. the expectation of a random variable $X$ on the event $A$ would be $\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_A]$ where $\mathsf 1_\cdot$ denotes the indicator function.